# How to get the correct output in this homework problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As a freelancer I picked up a homework project but I got stuck with it. How can I get this code to get the desired output? The code is:

```
n = int(input('\n Enter Your Value of N : '))

answer = [[1]]
for i in range(2, n+1):
    t = ([i]*((2*i)-3))
    answer.insert(n,t)
    for a in answer:
        a.insert(0,i)
        a.append(i)
        answerfinal = []
    for a in answer:
        answerfinal.append("".join(str(a)))
    for a in answerfinal:
        print(a)
```

The desired output is to be like this:

```
Input : 5

Output : 

    555555555
    544444445
    543333345
    543222345
    543212345
    543222345
    543333345
    544444445
    555555555
```

The output I am getting is this:

```
Enter Your Value of N : 5   

[2, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
[3, 2, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 2, 2, 3]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5]
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: It would help if you showed us the output you're getting now.

Comment: I have edited my Question with the output I am getting Can you help me now?

Comment: To be clear, what you want for input `n` is a bunch of concentric squares where square `k` is made of number `k` and has side length `2*k-1`

Comment: It's hard to imagine who would pay a freelancer to do this kind of task, except a student cheating on their homework.

Comment: To be honest A student is paying me to do this work done

Comment: As @BallpointBen said is correct but I want to get the input in a int type and print the Output

Comment: @ShayCormac so why did they ask you...?

Comment: He Posted his Proposal on freelancer.com So I am doing it Please help me to get this done

Comment: I started with  `for x in range(n, 0, -1): row = [max(x, y) for y in range(n, 0, -1)]`, added some more code and it worked. I even have a solution in 2 lines (including the printing), so it shouldn't be overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I liked the problem, that is why I am posting my solution.
But the next time, please, don't ask to solve your homework!

The strategy I have used is to generate first what I think is the core block of your result, the middle line `mid`.

Next, I have built `arr1` by substituting `n` with `n+1`, `n` goes from 1 to 4, in this case.

At this point, you have the bottom half of your output in place. The top half (`arr2`) can be built by reverse iteration of the bottom half.

Join the two arrays and the job is done.

```
x = 5

arr1 = []
mid = list(range(x,1,-1))
mid.extend(range(1,x+1,1))
mid = ''.join([str(_) for _ in mid])
arr1.append(mid)
for n in range(1, x):
    mid = mid.replace(f'{n}',f'{n+1}')
    arr1.append(mid)

arr2 = []
for item in list(reversed(arr1))[:-1]:
    arr2.append(item)

arr2.extend(arr1)

for item in arr2:
    print(item)
```

The output is as expected

```
555555555
544444445
543333345
543222345
543212345
543222345
543333345
544444445
555555555
```

There must be a better way to achieve the same result. It's up to you to find it!

Comment: Thanks a lot @alec_djinn It helped me a lot

Comment: (Seriously: in this case OP is going to blindly copy and paste your code without learning anything, hand it over to somebody else who's _paying_ for it, who won't understand it, and will submit it for credit.)

Comment: @Chris You are super fast! I still need to add some extra comments. But yes, thanks for the remark.

Comment: Btw can anyone explain me what does ast.literal_eval(some_string) returns ????

Comment: @ShayCormac, run it and see? Or look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
for i in range(-number + 1, number):
    n = abs(i) + 2
    print("".join([
        str(j) for j in 
        list(range(number, n - 2, -1)) + # first part (54321)
        ([n - 1] * (n * 2 - 4)) + # middle part (1111)
        list(range(n, number + 1)) # end part (2345)
    ])) # "".join converts the list to a string
```

The

> for i in range

is for the vertical axis, the statement,

> "".join(str(j) for j in list(...) + [...] + list(...))

joins the lists together and converts it to string,

> list(range(number, n - 2, -1))

is for the start beginning (here: 54321),

> ([n - 1] * (n * 2 - 4))

is for the middle part (here: 1111), and

> list(range(n, number + 1))

is the ending (here: 2345)

Comment: I will comment it in a second

Comment: Just a question, why did i get a downvote on my answer?

Comment: Unless someone explains their downvote, we won't ever know, but readers can certainly guess. Either the question author is a student wanting to cheat, or they are a freelancer helping a student cheat. Some readers will want to discourage that, because somewhere in the world, a student may be getting a grade that he or she does not deserve. They may cheat their way through their education and then scrape into a software engineering role, where their colleagues have to put up with their shoddy and incompetent work.